# Canonical Q/A for 'Module 'x' has no attribute 'y' in Python

Tags: discussion, canonical

This seems to come up quite a lot.

In Python, someone writes a script which has the same name as a module they want to import from it. The import succeeds, but when they try to access an attribute of the module, this fails with the `AttributeError: module 'x' has no attribute 'y'` error, because the name of their script is shadowing the module.

It's so common that I'd have thought there must be a canonical dupe-target, but I can't find one.

Comment: https://sopython.com/canon/96/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-foobar/ and [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](//stackoverflow.com/q/36250353)

Comment: Favourited. Thanks @MartijnPieters - my search-fu must be weak today.

Comment: Very common errors generally need about two dozen questions to get canonically answered.  This one has *four thousand* questions.  Holy cow.  This could only explode like this when users do not want a canonical answer.  Presumably you'd have to answer for the specific module that is named in the message.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) maintains a [list of canonical posts](https://sopython.com/canon/). A quick search for *module* turns up https://sopython.com/canon/96/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-foobar/, which links to [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Please join the chat room, there's people there 24/7 that can help with issues like these.

Comment: Thanks - I've never really ventured into the chat rooms. I'll go and lurk...